# Pip not installing during virtualenv venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualbox, virtual-environment

I have created several virtual environments using `virtualenv venv` for the past few weeks. But it suddenly does not work. When I do a deeper check, the installation will stopped at pip stage. I have tried `virtualenv venv` and `virtualenv venv -v`. I have also tried `virtualenv venv --no-pip` which further confirms that the issue lies within pip.

```
  Looking in links: file:///C:/users/mong%20chang%20hsi/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/lib/>site-packages/virtualenv_support
  Collecting setuptools
  Collecting pip
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Mong Chang Hsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\virtualenv-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==16.6.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "c:\users\mong chang hsi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 867, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "c:\users\mong chang hsi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1159, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "c:\users\mong chang hsi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1009, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "c:\users\mong chang hsi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1096, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "c:\users\mong chang hsi\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 934, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this `python3 -m venv name_of_environment`